# How to connect Raspberry PI to Android without cutting the sound?

Tags: bluetooth, connection, android-bluetooth, raspberry-pi4

I am working on a project using a Raspberry PI4 under Bullseye 64 bits and an Android smartphone. There is no Wi-Fi nor internet available.
I would like to inform Android the Raspberry has just started.
In the past I did something similar: when I turn may car on, I get a callback on my phone. To do that, on boot, I register a broadcast for `android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED`. It works fine, because as soon as I turn the car on, the Bluetooth of the car connects to the phone.
Now in my current project the car role is played by the raspberry PI. I have connected the smartphone to the Raspberry PI using the standard Android UI. It works fine.
Later, from the Raspberry PI I run `bluetoothctl connect MAC` where `MAC` is the mac address of my smartphone. It works well, the devices are connected, and I get the callback in Android.

The problem comes from the fact the smartphone sees the Raspberry **like headset**, so I cannot hear the sounds played on my smartphone : there are send to Raspberry.
I spends days trying to fix that issue, but I did not found any solution. For example, if I tried to modify the `bluetoothd` daemon on the PI like this:
`ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=*`
It is not working : I cannot connect the PI from the smartphone. I guess it is due to the profiles implemented in Android: If I remove everything from Bluetooth daemon Android does not found anything suitable.

Have you any idea how I could solve the issue?
Notice I could disconnect few seconds after connection as all I need is the information the Raspberry has started but I am not happy with that solution, the user may notice the interruption.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. It may have been depracated or sidelined by dBus, so no promises. Try deleting the Pi's audio service with sdptool.
First list the services:

sudo sdptool records local

Find the service that looks like an audio link and note its handle which will be listed like this:

Service RecHandle: 0x10002

Then delete the service

sudo sdptool del 10002

Comment: Thank you @petzval. Here is an extract output of  `sudo sdptool records local` : ` Service Name: Audio Sink`,  `Service Name: Audio Source`, `Service Name: Headset Voice gateway`, `Service Name: Headset unit` Which one(s) should I remove ?

Comment: You say the Pi is seen as a headset, so I guess Headset unit, but it's down to trial and error. If you need to restore a deleted service, sudo sdptool will print a help screen and list the available services (DID SP DUN...) and they can be added via for example sudo sdptool add HS  (HS is Headset and A2SNK is probably Audio sink)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your suggestions, but I did not succeed.

### Firstly I tried the usual process

Connect the smartphone to the PI from the standard Android UX.
On the PI, in `bluetoothctl`

I see this :

```
[NEW] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy MyPhoneName
Request confirmation
[agent] Confirm passkey 798942 (yes/no): yes
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy Modalias: usb:v0FCEp020Dd0010
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 10000057-5749-5448-0037-000000000000
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: a82efa21-ae5c-3dde-9bbc-f16da7b16c5a
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy Paired: yes
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy Connected: no
```

Android tried several times the connections.

I tried again from Android I see this :

```
[CHG] Device 3C:01:EF:6F:A8:BF Connected: yes
Authorize service
[agent] Authorize service 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (yes/no): yes
```

Next step : forget the PI from the phone and remove the phone from the PI

> bluetoothctl remove yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy

### Secondly remove the records using sdptool

Now removing the 2 records:  (I did that after adding ‘—compat’ to bluetoothd in order to make sdptool working):

```
$ sudo sdptool browse local
Browsing FF:FF:FF:00:00:00 ...
Service RecHandle: 0x10000
Service Class ID List:
  "PnP Information" (0x1200)
Profile Descriptor List:
  "PnP Information" (0x1200)
    Version: 0x0103

Browsing FF:FF:FF:00:00:00 ...
Service Search failed: Invalid argument
Service Name: Generic Access Profile
Service Provider: BlueZ
Service RecHandle: 0x10001
Service Class ID List:
  "Generic Access" (0x1800)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 31
  "ATT" (0x0007)
    uint16: 0x0001
    uint16: 0x0005

Service Name: Generic Attribute Profile
Service Provider: BlueZ
Service RecHandle: 0x10002
Service Class ID List:
  "Generic Attribute" (0x1801)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 31
  "ATT" (0x0007)
    uint16: 0x0006
    uint16: 0x000f

Service Name: Device Information
Service Provider: BlueZ
Service RecHandle: 0x10003
Service Class ID List:
  "" (0x180a)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 31
  "ATT" (0x0007)
    uint16: 0x0010
    uint16: 0x0012

Service Name: **Headset Voice gateway**
Service RecHandle: 0x10004
Service Class ID List:
  "Headset Audio Gateway" (0x1112)
  "Generic Audio" (0x1203)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 12
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Headset" (0x1108)
    Version: 0x0102

Service Name: **Headset unit**
Service RecHandle: 0x10005
Service Class ID List:
  "Headset" (0x1108)
  "" (0x1131)
  "Generic Audio" (0x1203)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 3
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Headset" (0x1108)
    Version: 0x0102

So I removed the to last services :
$ sudo sdptool del 0x10004
Service Record deleted.
$ sudo sdptool del 0x10005
Service Record deleted.
```

If again I run `sudo sdptool browse local`, there are gone.

But If I  run

> bluetootctl show

I do not see any changes :

```
[bluetooth]# show
Controller xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (public)
        Name: mypi
        Alias: mypi
        Class: 0x00200000
        Powered: yes
        Discoverable: yes
        DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
        Pairable: yes
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0537
        Discovering: no
        Roles: central
        Roles: peripheral
Advertising Features:
        ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
        SupportedInstances: 0x05 (5)
        SupportedIncludes: tx-power
        SupportedIncludes: appearance
        SupportedIncludes: local-name
```

Again, paring from the smartphone :

```
[NEW] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy MyPhoneName
Request confirmation
[agent] Confirm passkey 887536 (yes/no): yes
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy Modalias: usb:v0FCEp020Dd0010
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: 10000057-5749-5448-0037-000000000000
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy UUIDs: a82efa21-ae5c-3dde-9bbc-f16da7b16c5a
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy Paired: yes
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy Connected: no
```

The connection is failing.
I guess Android to not get any suitable services, so it gave up.

I have noticed one thing: if I restart the  bluetooth daemon (sudo systemctl restart bluetooth) the 2 records are back.
I am wondering if there is something in Raspberry PI OS which force these 2 services.

### Conclusion

I am stuck.
I thought I had solved my problem because when I initiate the connection to phone from the PI (after the pairing from the phone), Android triggers an event `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` followed by a `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` which is enough for me.
Unfortunately, it only works for a while. If I wait too long, I can't get it to work.

Comment: You have obviously put significant effort into solving the problem, which is fantastic, however this is not an answer. Next time it would be best to edit your question and add what you have tried there instead of posting a answer.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Next time I will edit my question. Now I think I am going to create a BLE device on the Raspberry PI rather than using out of the box.